# How to display all variable with/without a null value?

Tags: php, sql

Currently, the codes I've done below are the codes that will only display the courses that have a tutor_id assigned to them. However, what I want is to display the courses that are not assigned the tutor_id as well as 'No tutor has been assigned to this course'. Tutor_id is a NULL variable in the database.

(storing in navigation pages)

```
$arrItems = executeSelectQuery("SELECT * FROM course, category, tutor WHERE course.Category_id = category.Category_id AND course.Tutor_id = tutor.Tutor_id");

$totalDesign = executeSelectQuery("SELECT * FROM course, category, tutor WHERE course.Category_id = category.Category_id AND course.Tutor_id = tutor.Tutor_id");
$numrows = count($totalDesign);

$arrItems = executeSelectQuery("SELECT * FROM course, category, tutor WHERE course.Category_id = category.Category_id AND course.Tutor_id = tutor.Tutor_id ORDER BY course.Course_name ASC LIMIT $offset, $rowsPerPage");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM course
INNER JOIN category ON course.Category_id = category.Category_id
OUTER JOIN tutor ON course.Tutor_id = tutor.Tutor_id 
ORDER BY course.Course_name ASC LIMIT $offset, $rowsPerPage
```

Outer join provides just the functionality you are after. All
courses will be selected with some containing null values in the
Tutor_id field. Identify when this happens in your code and print 
"No tutor has been assigned to this course" on these occasions.

Answer (score 0):

Try that

```
SELECT * FROM course, category, tutor WHERE course.Category_id = category.Category_id AND ( course.Tutor_id = tutor.Tutor_id OR course.Tutor_id IS NULL )
```

Answer (score 0):

To get a separate list of no-tutor courses:

```
$arrItems = executeSelectQuery("SELECT * FROM course WHERE Tutor_id is NULL");
```